# No errors in Postgres error log or in VS code are shown when code is executed. Trying to insert data into PostgreSQL. Table remains empty

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, database-connection

My goal is to **create a forum with an option to create a topic** with detail, name, email, and datetime being the fields asked for by PHP. Create_topic.php is the file that contains the basic layout of the form. The data in these fields is grabbed in POST once submit is pressed.

Once submit is pressed the action = "add_topic.php"(the code below). The file that will handle the data I am attempting to insert. at the bottom of the script there is a hyperlink which leads to the place that the topic is going to be. I haven't gotten to the actual display part since there is no data in DB to display. Only in POST which is temporary.

**What's the problem**

No errors in Postgres error log or in VS code are shown when code is executed. Trying to insert data into PostgreSQL. Table remains empty.

**What I've tried**

I've tried changing the place holder values from ":" to "$" to "?" and none of these seem to do the trick.
I've made sure that the there is an actual connection by causing purposeful hiccups in code.
PGSQL log lets me know when there aren't enough params supplied or when I attempt to insert data into a table that does not exist. So... there is a connection....I think.
I can insert data from the terminal just fine.(I also have other code in my home page that is functional. I bring up that code because it involves entry and retrieval from PostgreSQL)
No errors in VS CODE OR LOG when code is executed otherwise.
Thank you for all your help amigos. Novice at best. Just trying to move on to the next challenge. May the force be with you

```
<?php  

$tbl_name='forum_question'; 
require('forum_config.php');

try{
     $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass) or die();
     
}catch(PDOException $e)
{ 
    if(!$db){
        print'no luck';
        echo 'no luck';
       
    }
    echo-$e->getMessage(); 
}
 
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$datetime=date("d/m/y h:i:s"); 
$inputdata = array ($topic, $detail, $name, $email, $datetime);

$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO forum_question(topic, detail, _name, email, _datetime) VALUES (:topic, :detail, :_name, :email, :_datetime)');

$query->bindParam(":topic",$topic);
$query->bindParam(":detail",$detail);
$query->bindParam(":_name",$name);
$query->bindParam(":email",$email);
$query->bindParam(":_datetime",$datetime);
$query->execute(array ($topic, $detail, $name, $email, $datetime)); 

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($query){
    
    echo "successful connection to DB $dbname<BR><br>";
    echo "Below we have proof that POST data has been captured.
    <br> The goal is to store in the TABLE $tbl_name which is inside the DATABASE $dbname. 
    <br> The captured data shall be displayed in desired forum.";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $result;


    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from forum_question");
    $query->execute();

    $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    
    echo $inputdata;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
   
    echo "<br>";
    echo "topic: $topic";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "detail: $detail";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "name: $name";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "email: $email";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=main_forum_life.php>View your topic</a>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo"<br>";
   
    }
    else {
    echo "<a href='error.php'>No biggie. Let us regroup.</a>";
   
    die();
    }
```

?>

```
/* Below is the SQL for the table that I am trying to insert $topic, $detail, $name, $email and $datetime into. */
```

CREATE TABLE forum_question(

```
forum_question_uid SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
topic VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
detail TEXT NOT NULL,
_name VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
_datetime VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
_view SERIAL,
reply SERIAL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `AUTOCOMMIT` turned off? see [url]https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html

Otherwise you need to do a `commit` after the insert.

You're not getting an error in this case because nothing went wrong. The data got inserted and then rolled back when the connection ended.

Comment: Wow Will look into this. I honestly didn't even know about this. Will be right back.

Comment: Hey Salik. I believe that I do. I went into the terminal and the command  \echo :AUTOCOMMIT returned "on"

Comment: Also. I have code running elsewhere involving data entry and retrieval. It works fine. For some reason this one isn't working. I am asking php to require the same config file. There is a connection and Auto commit is on. Thank you once again Sarik.

Comment: Also. PostgreSQL set AUTOCOMMIT to ON by default. https://dzone.com/articles/autocommit-in-postgresqls-psql

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP person.

Answer (score 0):

the number of column doesn't match the number of value you miss column "topic":

$pgquery = 'INSERT INTO forum_question( detail, _name, email, _datetime) VALUES (:topic, :detail, :_name, :email, :_datetime)';

Comment: That is my fault. I made a mistake transferring from IDE to stack overflow. will correct now. Thank you.

Comment: `$pgquery` isn't used